# Trigger @Url Action using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I download and replace an image using an action to controller after the page has loaded?

HTML:

```
<img id="profileWindowPictureContent" src="@Url.Action("GetLargeProfilePic", "Home")"/>
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: @Url.Action in razor is resolved in execution time, you are mixing javascript with c#/razor. What is what you want to do?

Comment: What do you mean `trigger`?

Comment: I mean prompt the razor call src="@Url.Action("GetLargeProfilePic", "Home")" again.

Comment: Do you mean you want to re-download an image from a controller action (which by this point will have been rendered to a client side URL), replacing the existing image on the page?

Comment: @pwdst exactly what I'm looking to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img id="my-image" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home")"/>
<button id="reload-button">Reload image</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#reload-button").click(function()
        {
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home")"
            })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                $("#my-image").removeAttr("src")
                              .attr("src", 
                                    "@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home")");
                alert("Image reloaded");
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

When you click the "Reload Image" button, you will do an ajax call which will force your browser to reload the image by removing the src attribute from the image and then re-adding it.

Also, instead of a button click, you can choose any other trigger you want.